# Problem about Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os

I try to write an extension and i saw the very restricted policy security.
I should create an extension that allows me to listen and download podcast from web. It is possible?
I use Chrome OS with VMWare, this OS has additional Api than Google Chrome Browser?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to have a content scripts that executes on every page looking for specific media content.  The content page could send a request back to the extension to indicate it has found a media file and using the URL you could play it in an  tag inside the extension.